# Send TCP request and get a response

Tags: android, sockets, tcp

I try to send some String with TCP request.My serverID and port is correct.I search about TCP request and found some example or tutorials.Here is a my source.

```
    public class TcpClient {

    public static final String SERVER_IP = "my server ip"; //server IP address
    public static final int SERVER_PORT = 8022;
    // message to send to the server
    private String mServerMessage;
    // sends message received notifications
    private OnMessageReceived mMessageListener = null;
    // while this is true, the server will continue running
    private boolean mRun = false;
    // used to send messages
    private PrintWriter mBufferOut;
    // used to read messages from the server
    private BufferedReader mBufferIn;

    /**
     * Constructor of the class. OnMessagedReceived listens for the messages received from server
     */
    public TcpClient(OnMessageReceived listener) {
        mMessageListener = listener;
    }

    /**
     * Sends the message entered by client to the server
     *
     * @param message text entered by client
     */
    public void sendMessage(String message) {
        if (mBufferOut != null && !mBufferOut.checkError()) {
            mBufferOut.println(message);
            mBufferOut.flush();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Close the connection and release the members
     */
    public void stopClient() {

        mRun = false;

        if (mBufferOut != null) {
            mBufferOut.flush();
            mBufferOut.close();
        }

        mMessageListener = null;
        mBufferIn = null;
        mBufferOut = null;
        mServerMessage = null;
    }

    public void run() {

        mRun = true;

        try {
            //here you must put your computer's IP address.
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);

            Log.e("TCP Client", "C: Connecting...");

            //create a socket to make the connection with the server
            Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVER_PORT);

            try {

                //sends the message to the server
                mBufferOut = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);

                //receives the message which the server sends back
                mBufferIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));


                //in this while the client listens for the messages sent by the server
                while (mRun) {

                    mServerMessage = mBufferIn.readLine();

                    if (mServerMessage != null && mMessageListener != null) {
                        //call the method messageReceived from MyActivity class
                        mMessageListener.messageReceived(mServerMessage);
                    }

                }

                Log.e("RESPONSE FROM SERVER", "S: Received Message: '" + mServerMessage + "'");

            } catch (Exception e) {

                Log.e("TCP", "S: Error", e);

            } finally {
                //the socket must be closed. It is not possible to reconnect to this socket
                // after it is closed, which means a new socket instance has to be created.
                socket.close();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

            Log.e("TCP", "C: Error", e);

        }

    }

    //Declare the interface. The method messageReceived(String message) will must be implemented in the MyActivity
    //class at on asynckTask doInBackground
    public interface OnMessageReceived {
        public void messageReceived(String message);
    }

}
```

**I'm using this class in mainActivity like this**

```
    public class SocketActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TcpClient mTcpClient;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_socket);
        new ConnectTask().execute("");
        if (mTcpClient != null) {
            mTcpClient.sendMessage("hello");
        }

    }


    public class ConnectTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, TcpClient> {

        @Override
        protected TcpClient doInBackground(String... message) {

            //we create a TCPClient object
            mTcpClient = new TcpClient(new TcpClient.OnMessageReceived() {
                @Override
                //here the messageReceived method is implemented
                public void messageReceived(String message) {
                    //this method calls the onProgressUpdate
                    publishProgress(message);
                }
            });
            mTcpClient.run();

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
            //response received from server
            Log.e("test", "response " + values[0]);
            //process server response here....

        }
    }
}
```

I debuged my source and problem is this line

```
 mServerMessage = mBufferIn.readLine();
```

**Any solutions?**

Comment: `debuged my source and problem is this line` Well then please tell which problem you have. Should we guess?

Comment: `if (mTcpClient != null) {
            mTcpClient.sendMessage("hello");
        }`. You cannot send a message there as you just started your AsyncTask but doInBoackground() is not executed yed. So there is not yet a connection as for that .run() has to be called before.

Comment: It looks as if you added a lot of pieces together in the wrong way.

Comment: When exactly would the server send a message? You did tell nothing about how server and client are supposed to communicate.

Comment: I comment sendMessage method  @greenapps

Comment: Are you serious? You did not react on nearly all i said. I wonder why you posted if you dont react.